# Converting RGB to grayscale python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have been converting rgb images to grayscale images, below is the code

```
import numpy
import glob
import cv2
import csv
import math
import os
import string
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from PIL import Image

mylist = [f for f in glob.glob("*.jpg")]

for imagefile in mylist:
    img_color = cv2.imread(imagefile)
    image = cv2.resize(img_color,(100,100),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img_gray = rgb2gray(image)
    img_gray.flatten()
```

Im not getting the new image saved into my current folder.
Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: You should write the image using `cv2.imwrite("new_img.jpg", img_gray)`

Comment: Not working, I tried it

Comment: make sure you have images in mylist

Comment: Yeah the images are present in mylist, I read all the images in the current directory and printed the list out.

Comment: Screenshot of the list https://imgur.com/4l1FB66

Comment: You don't appear to be writing the image to disk, so how were you hoping it would work? Also, if you want a greyscale image, you can just open it in greyscale in the first place by changing the second parameter to `cv2.imread()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because of skimage. why dont you use just opencv.

```
import numpy
import glob
import cv2
import csv
import math
import os
import string
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from PIL import Image

mylist = [f for f in glob.glob("*.jpg")]

for imagefile in mylist:
    img_color = cv2.imread(imagefile)
    image = cv2.resize(img_color,(100,100),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #img_gray = rgb2gray(image)
    img_gray.flatten()
    cv2.imwrite("gray"+imagefile,img_gray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this in one step if you want by adding an additional parameter to imread like this:

```
import cv2
imagefile = "path/to/file/filename.jpg"
gray = cv2.imread(imagefile, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add code for saving image file:

```py
import numpy
import glob
import cv2
import csv
import math
import os
import string
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.io import imsave    # skimage method for saving image
from PIL import Image

mylist = [f for f in glob.glob("*.jpg")]

for imagefile in mylist:
    img_color = cv2.imread(imagefile)
    image = cv2.resize(img_color,(100,100),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img_gray = rgb2gray(image)
    img_gray.flatten()
    imsave("gray"+imagefile, img_gray)  # save the image
```

Or using opencv

```py
img_gray = img_gray*255
cv2.imwrite("gray"+imagefile, img_gray.astype("uint8"))
```

But if you want to implement this entirely in skimage

```py
import glob
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.transform import resize

mylist = [f for f in glob.glob("*.jpg")]

for imagefile in mylist:
    img_color = imread(imagefile)
    image = resize(img_color, (100, 100))
    img_gray = rgb2gray(image)
    img_gray.flatten()
    imsave("gray" + imagefile, img_gray)
```

Comment: I get this error when I implement entirely in skimage  NameError: name 'im_path' is not defined